# Ruby on Rails - Doesn't create script/server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying for two days to install Ruby on Rails on windows xp (I am a noob at RoR, first time using it).

I am reading some tutorials online how to install it. I have installed Ruby, installed Mysql and installed Rails by `gem install rails`.

Now when I create a new app by `rails new myapp` then `cd myapp` and then `ruby script/server`, it says:

> ruby: No such file or directory --
>   script/server (LoadError)

In the script directory there is no 'server' file, there is only a rails file.

I have followed the tutorial correctly and have double checked I and creating the app correctly. This is the tutorial link: http://allaboutruby.wordpress.com/2006/01/09/installing-rails-on-windows-step-by-step-tutorial/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you've done gem install rails then it will have grabbed v3.0.6 rails which changed (at v3) to use `rails server` to start the server.

Comment: Thanks I have just tried this and it says "<[31mCould not find gem 'sqlite3 (>=0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.<[0m"   Confused lol

Comment: For the sqlite3 problem you need to run (inside your website dir) bundle install

Comment: Yep done that, but when I try to rails server it' says sqlite3.dll was not found. I have tried to re-install it as well :/

Comment: Fixed that, but it's now displaying "the procedure entry point sqlite3_column_database_name could not be located in the dynamic link library sqlite3.dll". Please help lol

Comment: I noticed that in many sites the documentation is not updated. We see `rails script/server` everywhere and not `rails server`. A lot of new commands are not presented. Even `rails yourapp` seems not to work, you have to type `rails new yourapp`. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-examples.htm

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Rails 3 you need to use:

```
rails server
```

Comment: Thanks I have just tried this and it says "<[31mCould not find gem 'sqlite3 (>=0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.<[0m" Confused lol

Comment: have you tried "gem install sqlite3"? Always developed in Linux or Mac OS

Answer (score 4):

you can use in new ruby ...installtion

in command prompt

> c:\ruby\bin>rails new filename

where filename is your new project name
to create a new ruby project. and don't use the reserved ruby reseverd word like test

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using Rails 3, so the proper command is `ruby rails server`.

Comment: That says "ruby: No such file or directory -- rails (LoadError)"

Answer (score 3):

Your tutorial is very old 2006...

You should definitly check [railsinstaller.org/](http://www.railsinstaller.org/) to use rails on windows

> I am a noob at RoR, first time using it

here is a good documentation [guides.rubyonrails.org/](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

and you should play with [railsforzombies.org/](http://railsforzombies.org/)

welcome,

cheers

Answer (score 3):

From your app directory, run

```
ruby script/rails server
```

This should work even on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use shortcut:

`rails s`

Answer (score 0):

Kelvin, congratulations, this command works exactly as you described in windows 8.
hugs...

```
ruby script / rails server
```

Comment: FYI Such messages should be added **as comments** to the related answer, not as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If everything is properly installed and `rails is 4.0` then the **command** is

> `user@sony-vaio:~/sample_rails/myApp$  rails server`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
```