# Ruby on Rails -Sqlite3 procedure could not be located in the dynamic link library sqlite3 dll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new to Ruby on rails and have just previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661554/ruby-on-rails-doesnt-create-script-server) about the script/server not being created. And found out that it's because of the sqlite not found. So I installed the gem and that's not working either, it was saying that the .dll wasn't found. So I used this quite tutorial to get the .dll and placed it in my /ruby/bin.

That fixed the .dll missing issue but has caused another problem. When I try to start the server (rails server), it says:

> The procedure entry point
>   sqlite_column_database_name could not
>   be located in the dynamic link library
>   sqlite3.dll

Please help, I am a noob at this Ruby on Rails stuff :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run "gem list sqlite". Post the output.

I suspect you installed sqlite-ruby instead of sqlite3 gem. The old gem is trying to call an old function in the dll that doesn't exist anymore.

If you don't see "sqlite3" in your gem list, run "gem install sqlite3".