# Ruby command/server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i try to run ruby on rails application via

```
      ruby script/server
```

it give's me this error :

```
      script/server:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- commands/server (LoadError)
      from script/server:4:in `<main>'
```

what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - Doesn't create script/server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661554/ruby-on-rails-doesnt-create-script-server)

Answer (score 1):

You should run the server with `rails server`

Here is related link: [Ruby on Rails - Doesn't create script/server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661554/ruby-on-rails-doesnt-create-script-server)

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 4**, proper way (using generated binaries under `bin/`):

```
bin/rails server
```

If you're upgrading from previous Rails version, you can generate `bin/` folder with:

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

**Rails 3**:

```
bundle exec rails server
```

Comment: there is no bin folder then what should i do ?

Comment: I got these files and folders : app, db,   Gemfile,       lib,  public,    README,  test,  vendor,
config,  doc,  Gemfile.lock,  log,  Rakefile,  script,  tmp

Comment: @TouqeerShafi run `rake rails:update:bin` to generate these binaries.

Comment: its says `rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails:update:bin'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
`

Comment: Are you sure you are using Rails 4? If not (Rails 3), just use `bundle exec rails server`.

Comment: Check this

[root@localhost web]# which rails
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rails

But when i try this command 
`bundle exec rails server`

it says : Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: You should run that command from application root path, where you have the `Gemfile`.

Comment: I told you there is no Gemfile, i've got this package from a developer.

Comment: Nops, in your first comment you said: `app, db, Gemfile, lib, public, README, test, vendor, config, doc, Gemfile.lock, log, Rakefile, script, tmp`. So, you have Gemfile there.

Comment: sorry its my mistake, i've never got this file from developer :(, actually i copied this from other application.