# Ruby on Rails. There is no script folder in the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, project-structure

I study Rails with the book "Head First Rails"

steps are:

1. to create my app with the command "rails new tickets"
2. run server with "ruby script/server"
3. "ruby script/generate scaffold ..."

But there is no script folder in  the project and I get an error "ruby: No such file or directory -- script/generate (LoadError)"
I've found that I need to use "ruby s" to start the server.
But how can I run script/generate?
Is it a new style of generating folders in the rails project and there is no more script folder? Or did I smth wrong?

I have ruby version 2.4.4 and rails 5.2.1

Comment: "Head First Rails" is pretty dated at this point. I believe the `script` directory was removed around rails 3 or 4. If you're looking for a good place to start, Michael Hartl's "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" is the general go-to for a lot of beginners: https://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - Doesn't create script/server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661554/ruby-on-rails-doesnt-create-script-server)

Comment: [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) one also good point for beginners, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nowadays it is used `rails` instead of `ruby script/`, so try `rails server` or `rails generate scaffold`